# How to add font in wordpress

Tags: theme-development

I have a oswald.woff font file downloaded from some free fonts site.  Using ftp i have created folder called fonts in the themes folders. (i.e /wp-content/themes/esplanade/fonts). In the fonts folder i put the oswald.woff file.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Oswald";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local("Oswald Regular"), local("Oswald-Regular"), url("fonts/oswald.woff") format("woff");
}
```

I use this font for an heading h1. When  open my site, it says "www.mysite.com/fonts/oswald.woff" (mysite.com used for representation, its not the origianl site) not found in the firebug errors console.

how to get the url of the file oswald.woff

Comment: No need to install the file for Oswald as its included in Google Web Fonts so you can load it using wp_enqueue_scripts http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/144785/9884

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be in www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/esplanade/fonts/oswald.woff

Comment: The the url worked. Now there is no error and the font file loads. but the font does not change. anything else is needed.

Comment: What about this answer doesn't satisfy the question? You said the url worked, the font not changing sounds like a completely new problem ( and one thats offtopic on this site as a pure css question )

Comment: I think, this should be the accepted answer. As it fixes the real problem@ incorrect font file src path. The accepted answer is simply an alternantive.

Comment: Sorry, the solution worked, (i.e: the url part). the css part i have to see. what is wrong. I have downloaded the woff url from the google url. Why the woff is not working

Comment: I have added the      @font-face {    font-family: "Oswald";    font-style: normal;    font-weight: 400;    src: local("Oswald Regular"), local("Oswald-Regular"), url("wp-content/themes/esplanade/fonts/oswald/oswald.woff") format("woff");       } . My website it radhanath-swami.info

Comment: basicall in the url part  i had to avoid the mysite.com  then it worked

Answer (score 1):

You're only including WOFF, so there's no fallback for browsers that don't support it. See this [article from CSS Tricks about @font-face](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/).

Unless you absolutely need to have the font included locally, why not load Oswald from Google Fonts? You can add Google Fonts using a plugin such as [WP Google Fonts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-fonts/), or as you're developing a theme, add the following in functions.php:

```
/** Load Google fonts */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_load_google_fonts' );

function custom_load_google_fonts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald', array(), PARENT_THEME_VERSION );
}
```

The add the following CSS (with fallback fonts):

```
h1 {
 font-family: "Oswald", Helevetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: i was using google fonts url. but later if one day google changes their url it can be a problem. so i want to load from my own site

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi google doesn't change its url, specially for things like fonts. Don't actually see your point here

Comment: fine. I will stick to google url

Comment: There's nothing wrong with serving fonts from local, but I'd suggest you use more than just WOFF. Also, you are getting the 404 on the .woff file as you're not referencing it correctly. Have a look at [this WPMU Dev article for more](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-custom-fonts-to-wordpress-with-font-face-and-css/).

Comment: As I can't comment on the other answer (lack of reputation points), I think the answer is that Santhosh hasn't changed his @font-face declaration. The URL works, as the WOFF file is located at www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/esplanade/fonts/oswald.woff. But you need to change    url("fonts/oswald.woff") to url("/wp-content/themes/esplanade/fonts/oswald.woff"). Then it will be correctly loaded.

Comment: i think changing the url to /wp-content/themes/esplanade/fonts/oswald.woff worked instead of mysite.com/wp-content/themes/esplanade/fonts/oswald.woff